# HttpClient PostAsync returns 500 when getting token

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpresponse, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to figure out what I can do (logging, things to check) before having to read server logs as I don't want to miss something stupid before requesting that.

Here is my code:

```
const string URL = "https://SomeURL/api/security/";
string urlParameters = string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}", username, password);
StringContent content = new StringContent(urlParameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
StringContent content = new StringContent(urlParameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var tokenResponse = client.PostAsync("token", content).Result;
```

I am a little newer to this so I'm not sure what to check next but have tried the same request using postman and get a response with my token so it looks like I am missing something or maybe formatting something incorrectly?

Comment: A 500 error is the fault of the server, not the client. If the client does something wrong, the server should return a 4xx error. So there might be a problem in your request, but since the server doesn't handle it properly, you can't know what it is. So you *have* to look at the server logs.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, I got a successful response using postman which is why I thought I'd post the question, to see if there;s something obvious I am missing.  But yeah, if nothing stands out to anyone, I will have to request them like you said.

Comment: Try using `FormUrlEncodedContent` rather than `StringContent`: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/8f9f21c7153122a1f509f27ee1fabf80.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Postman implicitly sends other headers, such as `User-Agent`, `Cookie`, `Accept-Language`, etc. Maybe the server is expecting those headers.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, thanks for your reply's.  I was actually looking for ideas on what I can try and that is exactly how you answered so that is much appreciated.  You helped me realise that I did not URL encode my parameters and the server was expecting it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not URL encode my parameters, here's the fix (probably a better way of doing it).

```
string urlParameters = string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(username), Uri.EscapeDataString(password));
```

Comment: Using `FormUrlEncodedContent` as I suggested in my comment takes care of encoding the values.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I did comment that your comment was what helped me get here.  I did not use FormURLEncodedContent because the object is a little bit more bulky.  Still a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was following an online course, and the code for setting the URL parameters were set like this:

```
public async Task<AuthenticatedUser> Authenticate(string userName, string password)
    {
        var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username ", "userName"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "password")
        });

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await apiClient.PostAsync("/Token", data))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuthenticatedUser>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
```

When testing, found that 500 error was being returned for the PostAsync call. I checked my URL address and parameters and they all looked correct. If I tested in Swagger, then I received a 200 status and token was shown.

Following the link by Thomas Levesque I changed how the data variables were set to :

```
var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["grant_type"] = "password",
            ["username"] = username,
            ["password"] = password
        });
```

Now the response status is 200 and the AuthenticatedUser model is populated correctly. However I couldn't understand why Dictionary seem to work and KeyValuePair didn't. So I created the list and then encoded it:

```
       var dataList = new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dataList);

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await apiClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, content))
```

This also worked. I freely admit that I do not fully understand why.....yet.